# How to import 3rd party js libraries into angular with the aot compiler

Tags: angular, angular2-opaquetoken

I am currently using an opaque token. I first define an opaque token in the common section of the project as follows:

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
export let JQ_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<any>('jQuery');
```

I then import this as follows into the :

```
import { JQ_TOKEN } from './common/index'; // (I'm using barrels for this import)
```

// I then define jquery to be the $ window object:

```
let jQuery: Object = window['$'];
```

// and then in the app providers, I have the following:

```
{ provide: JQ_TOKEN, useValue: jQuery },
```

// Then, I import the token into the component:

```
import { JQ_TOKEN } from '../jQuery.service';
```

// and inject it as follows

```
constructor(@Inject(JQ_TOKEN) private $: any) {}
```

This has allowed me to define interfaces with intellisense, for example:

```
import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core';

export let TOASTR_TOKEN = new InjectionToken('toastr');

export interface Toastr {
  success (msg: string, title?: string): void;
  info (msg: string, title?: string): void;
  warning (msg: string, title?: string): void;
  error (msg: string, title?: string): void;
}
```

The above solution works really well, except when I want to do a production build with aot. Is there a way around this? 
That is, the following works:

```
ng build --prod --aot false
```

but this has runtime errors:

```
ng build --prod
```

I am using angular 4.3.4 with 1.2.8 of the cli.

I'm aware that I could probably use a plugin, but I would rather not do this, because it will mean a lot of changes to the project and may have it's own errors. I looked into the toastr plugin for angular and found that it kept vanishing when a page navigation was called, despite it being called after the page navigation. The same problem does not occur, if I use an OpaqueToken.